# Hibernate with postgreSQL 5.4.2 trying to save an object getting error

Tags: hibernate

```
May 05, 2019 2:36:32 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at org.vishal.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:12)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[5,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:103)
    ... 6 more
```

I am learning hibernate. Saving an object first time to postgreSQL, please help...................................................................

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "D:\Study Materials\Java\hibernate-release-5.4.2.Final.dtd">

- <hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I would add what it is you were doing that lead up to the Exception you got in addition to the codebase you are working with.

Comment: Trying to save one Object into database. this is my first code for hibernate. learning

Comment: The XML file probably starts with a UTF-8 BOM. Remove it, e.g. using Notepad++.

Comment: After using the said modification : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8 BOM'?>

I am getting ..

May 05, 2019 9:52:02 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to create stax reader

Comment: Unable to create stax reader

Comment: Your XML contains a dash before the `<hibernate-configuration>` element. Remove it.